# I can't redirect my domain to a subdomain using nginx location

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

I've a problem I tried to fix but I need help. I'm going to try to explain you what I need to do:

I have a nginx web server and I need to add a location to redirect my main page example.com to web.example.com but just this page. For anothers pages I need to use example.com/path.

For example any request to example.com it needs to redirecto to web.example.com (I can do that).

My problem start when I have a request to example.com/path and my location redirect to web.example.com/path that is not what I need.

I tried with some regular expresion but it does't work, any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you only need a redirect for the main page try exact match location

```
location = / {
  return 302 https://...$args;
}
```